# Efficiency terms in Stochastic Frontier Analysis can be greater than 1?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, estimation, stochastic-processes, truncated-normal-distribution

Let us consider a Cobb-Douglas production function with $Y$ being the output and $X$ being the input (assume for simplicity only one input) and a composite error term:
$$
Y = e^{\beta_0}X^{\beta_1}e^{v}e^{-u}
$$
The random error $v$ is assumed to be independent of $u$ follows a normal distribution $v_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_v)$. $u$ is a non-negative random variable that represents efficiency that follows a half-normal distribution $u \sim \mathcal{N}^+(0,\sigma_u)$. Technical efficiency can be generally derived as follows:
$$
e^{-u} = \frac{\text{factual production ($Y$)}}{\text{stochastic efficient production ($Y^*$)}},
$$
We know that by definition $u>0$. My question is: can $u$ be greater than 1?

- Technically since we have $Y \leq Y^*$, we must have $0 < u \leq 1$;
- If we consider for example $u \sim \mathcal{N}^+(0,0.50)$, then the inverse of the normal distribution with mean 0, std 0.5 and probability 0.9999 is $1.8595 > 1$. If we follow this point the maximum std allowed for the efficiency to be $0 < u \leq 1$ would be $\sigma_u \approx 0.2689$ where the inverse of the normal distribution with mean 0, std 0.2689 and probability 0.9999 is $1$.